When are two vectors collinear and coplanar?
My book says, If the position vectors , ,  of three points A,B,C and the scalars α, β, γ are such that
αa + βb + γc=0,and α + β + γ = 0,
then the three points A,B,C are collinear.
On the other hand,
If the position vectors a,b,c,d of the four points A,B,C,D (no three of which are collinear) and the non-zero scalars α,β,γ,δ are such that
αa+βb+γc+δd=0, and α+β+γ+δ=0,
then the four points A,B,C,D are coplanar.
But this book doesn't provide any reason why so. I tried a lot to prove these conditions, but failed. Why should, αa + βb + γc=0,and α + β + γ = 0,
mean A,B,C are collinear, and why should αa+βb+γc+δd=0, and α+β+γ+δ=0,
mean A,B,C,D are coplanar?
